# Regex for 9-digit number that does not start from the country code like prefix

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to filter out [potential Citizen Service Numbers](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgerservicenummer#11-proef) (BSN in Dutch) in specific texts which are also full of Dutch phone numbers. The phone numbers start with the +31 country code, while BSN numbers not.

Could someone help me to come up with the regular expression to match any 9-digit number that does not start with the `+<country-code-like-prefix><space>`?

For example, in the sentence:

> The number is +31 713176319 and 650068168 is another one.

I'd like to extract `650068168`, but not `713176319`. This might be solved by negative lookahead, but I was not able to find the right solution.

Comment: According to the [country code][1], we have the country codes like + 1-xxx. For example, the country Anguilla has the code 1-264. Doesn't regex for 9-digit number start from `+1 264` xxxxxxxxx?


  [1]: https://countrycode.org/

Comment: Thank you. @ThanLUONG I added more details to my questions to explain that it is specific to Dutch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative Lookbehind:

```regex
(?<!\+\d\d )\b\d{9}\b
```

This ensures that the 9-digit number is not preceded by ("+" followed by two digits followed by a space character).

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BWa7Kf/1)**.

Note that this will only work when the country code is two digits as in your example. To support country codes with one or 3 digits, things get a little tricky because python doesn't support Lookbehinds with non-fixed width. You could, however, use multiple Lookbehinds like this:

```regex
(?<!\+\d )(?<!\+\d{2} )(?<!\+\d{3} )\b\d{9}\b
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8DTFkn/1)**.

Comment: Wow, I knew about the look ahead feature but never thought there also a look behind. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `re.findall` here:

```
inp = "The number is +31 713176319 and 650068168 is another one."
matches = re.findall(r'(?:^|(?<!\S)(?!\+\d+)\S+ )(\d{9})\b', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['650068168']
```

The regex strategy here is to match a 9 digit standalone number when either it appears at the very start of the string, or it is preceded by some "word" (word being loosely defined as `\S+` here) which is *not* a country code prefix.

Here is an explanation of the regex used:

```
(?:
    ^          from the start of the string
    |          OR
    (?<!\S)    assert that what precedes is whitespace or start of the string
    (?!\+\d+)  assert that what follows is NOT a country code prefix
    \S+        match the non prefix "word", followed by a space
)
(\d{9})        match and capture the 9 digit number
\b             word boundary
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, I learned a lot about look behind.